# API Basic authentication

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-3

My application has spring 3 xml based configuration.
I'm calling a REST API from Postman (Not form based login) with username-password in Authorization header.
For authentication I have created authentication-provider which implements AuthenticationProvider.

```
    <security:authentication-manager>
            <security:authentication-provider ref="restAuthentication"/>
    </security:authentication-manager>
```

The problem is how to get credentials in the custom authentication-provider?
AuthenticationProvider does not provide authentication request with headers in overriding authenticate method.

---

Alternatively I tried extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint, but getting error while running application after afterPropertiesSet() method.

```
    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        setRealmName("Spring");
        super.afterPropertiesSet();
    }
```

Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Could not convert argument value of type [java.util.ArrayList] to required type [java.util.List]: Failed to convert value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'java.util.List'.

Please suggest which one of the two ways is appropriate and how can I resolve the conflict.

Comment: You really mean Spring 3 (2009) ? Or Spring Boot 3?

Comment: Spring 3 spring-beans-3.0.xsd, spring-security-3.2.xsd

Answer (score 0):

The responsibility to retrieve the credentials from the request and send it to the `AuthenticationManager` is usually from the `Filter`, see `BasicAuthenticationFilter`.

That said, you probably need a filter or a controller endpoint that converts the `HttpServletRequest` into an `Authentication` object and passes that object to the autowired `AuthenticationManager`.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

*SecurityConfiguration*

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    private BasicAuthManager basicAuthManager;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfiguration(BasicAuthManager basicAuthManager) {
        this.basicAuthManager = basicAuthManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        return http
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
                    .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .authenticationManager(basicAuthManager)
            .httpBasic(withDefaults())
            .build();
     }
}
```

*BasicAuthManager*

```
@Service
public class BasicAuthManager implements AuthenticationManager {
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public BasicAuthManager(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        final String username = authentication.getName();
        final String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
        UserDetails user;

        try {
            user = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException ex) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("User does not exists");
        }

        if (StringUtils.isBlank(password) || !passwordEncoder.matches(password, user.getPassword())) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Password is wrong");
        }

        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null, user.getAuthorities());
    }
}
```

*SecurityBeans*

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityBeans {
    @Value("${my.security.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${my.security.password}")
    private String password;
    @Value("${my.security.userRole}")
    private String userRole;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails userDetails = User
                .withUsername(username)
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode(password))
                .roles(userRole)
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetails);
    }
}
```